# Typescript generic interface according to value

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an event emitter that calls functions on the object. I'd like to be able to trigger events by their name, but still have the types of attributes each method accepts. So basically I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
enum Event {
    FirstEvent = 'first_event',
    SecondEvent = 'second_event'
}

interface EventAttributes {
    [Event.FirstEvent]: {
        prop1: string;
        prop2: number;
    };
    [Event.SecondEvent]: {
        prop3: boolean;
        prop4: string;
    };
}

class EventEmitter {
    [Event.FirstEvent]({prop1, prop2}) {
        //do something
    }

    [Event.SecondEvent]({prop3, prop4}) {
        //do something else
    }
}

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

// I can tell triggerEvent what type of Event I want
// And i'd like it to somehow use EventAttributes to return the corresponding props interface
function triggerEvent<Event>(event, props) {
  eventEmitter[event](props);
}
```

Example usage:

```
triggerEvent<Event.FirstEvent>({...This should know I need to pass prop1: string and prop2:number})
```

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually got this working like so:

```
function triggerEvent<EventName extends Event>(
  eventName: Event,
  props: EventAttributes[EventName]
) {
  eventEmitter[event](props);
}
```

Here's a working codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-edison-fnzbv?file=/src/App.tsx